# Looks like constructor didn't

Tags: c#

hi I'm learning c# Let's say I have this class

```
public class BST
{
public int value;
public BST left;
public BST right;
}
```

what is the name for public BST left, it's look like constructor but it's not

Comment: Is BST for binary search tree? Then it's the left child node. (And it doesn't look like a constructor.)

Comment: Just a member of BST

Comment: Why does it look like a constructor to you? Do you see any `()`? Do you see any `{}`? Why are you *not* confused by `public int value;`? Why should `public BST left;` seem different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have is

```
public BST left;
```

...which is declaring a [*field*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) in your class whose type is `BST`. This value of this field will be a [*reference*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) to some other `BST` object, or possibly itself, or possibly `null`.)

The closest looking thing to what you have that is actually a [*constructor*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) might look like

```
public BST(int left) {}
```

...which would be a constructor for the `BST` class that takes a single integer argument called `left`.

Remember that constructors look like methods with no return type, and the name of the method matches the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

It's a member field, just like `int value`.

You have a recursive data structure; a Binary Search Tree, based on the name.

> looks like constructor

No. Constructors don't have a return type, and need a code body and parentheses for zero or more parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just a member of BST , not constructor , constructor like this `BST() {}`